# Проверка наличия такого товара с таким id в корзине!

Tags: php

Нужно сделать условия к добавление в корзину. Если такой товар уже был добавлен в корзину но объем добавленного товара отличается от того объема товара который уже был добавлен в корзину то нужно создать новый товар и туда все эти данные перекинуть. Еще одно условие должно быть. Если такой товар уже добавлен в корзину и объем совпадает с уже добавленным товаром с объемом то должен добавляться один товар и просто количество добавляться к товару с который совпадает объем и id.

Проще говоря
Покупатель выбрал товар $newitemId = 1, $newitemCount = 4, $newitemVolume = 2л, $newitemVolumePrice = 500р.

Этот товар добавился в корзину.
айди - 1
кол-во - 4шт
Обьем - 2л
Цена за обьем 500р

Потом человек добавляет тот же товар с таким же обьемом только кол-во другое

$newitemId = 1, $newitemCount = 2, $newitemVolume = 2л, $newitemVolumePrice = 500р.

Уже в корзине должно быть
айди - 1
кол-во - 6шт
Обьъм - 2л
Цена за объем 500р

Потом человек добавляет тот же товар только обьем другой
$newitemId = 1, $newitemCount = 9, $newitemVolume = 5л, $newitemVolumePrice = 1200р.

Уже в корзине должно быть

Товар 1

айди - 1
кол-во - 6шт
Объем - 2л
Цена за объем 500р

Товар 2

айди - 1
кол-во - 9шт
Объем - 5л
Цена за объем 1200р

Если же человек добавил другой товар то просто фореч проходит и выводит так

Тот же покупатель с его же корзиной

Товар 1

айди - 1
кол-во - 6шт
Объем - 2л
Цена за обьем 500р

Товар 2

айди - 1
кол-во - 9шт
Обьем - 5л
Цена за объем 1200р

Товар 3

айди - 5
Кол-во - 4шт
Объем - 2л
Цена за объем - 300р

```
    if ($_POST['addToCart']) {
        if (!isset($_SESSION['basket'])) {
            $_SESSION['basket'] = [];
        }
        $newitemId .= $_POST['itemId'];
        $newitemCount = $_POST['itemCount'];
        $newitemVolume = $_POST['itemVolume'];
        $newitemVolumePrice = $_POST['VolumePrice'];

        $_SESSION['basket'][$newitemId][$newitemVolume]['itemCount'] += $newitemCount;
        $_SESSION['basket'][$newitemId][$newitemVolume]['itemVolume'] = $newitemVolume;
        $_SESSION['basket'][$newitemId][$newitemVolume]['VolumePrice'] .= $newitemVolumePrice;  
    }
```

Если можно то с выводом тоже покажите как будете форейчем проходить. Спасибо сразу

Comment: Как выглядит товар, который уже в корзине? Можно увидеть массив?

Comment: Я уже решил этот вопрос 

     if ($_SESSION['basket'][$_POST["itemId"]]) {
    if ($_SESSION['basket'][$_POST["itemId"]][$_POST["itemVolume"]]) {
     $tmp = $_SESSION['basket'][$_POST["itemId"]][$_POST["itemVolume"]]["count"];
     $_SESSION['basket'][$_POST["itemId"]][$_POST["itemVolume"]]["count"] = ((int)$tmp + (int)$_POST["itemCount"]);
     }
    }else{
     $_SESSION['basket'][$_POST["itemId"]][$_POST["itemVolume"]] = [
     "count" => $_POST["itemCount"],
     "itemVolume" => $_POST["itemVolume"],
     "VolumePrice" =>$_POST["VolumePrice"]
     ];
   }